# How to return all IDs that contain non-null values for each date of a date range?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with a table which contains monthly readings for a series of widgets an I need to return a list of all widget IDs which contain values for each date of a date range. The returned widget IDs cannot contain IDs which miss a value in the time period determined (e.g. in the example if February were missing) but can have data for time periods prior (e.g. in the example values for months prior to 2014 aren't necessary but are not exclusionary)

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/312e3/1

My goal is to return a list containing IDs that have values for January, February, and March. Per the example this would be IDs 1 and 2.

Fiddle above is somewhat representative of the data I am working with. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.  I added Oracle based on the SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to count the months in the overlap period:

```
select dt.id, count(distinct trunc(dt.occurrance, 'MON'))
from dates_test dt
where dt.occurrance >= trunc(date '2014-03-06', 'MON') and
      dt.occurrance < add_months(trunc(date '2014-04-06', 'MON'), 1)
group by dt.id     
having count(distinct trunc(dt.occurrance, 'MON')) =
           1 + months_between(trunc(date '2014-04-06', 'MON'), trunc(date '2014-03-06', 'MON'));
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/312e3/7) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It should work perfectly for my purposes